# Windows 7 Dell inspiron

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to format my C Drive using booltable USB drive. Windows 7 was already installed on the system but it crashed and won't restart.

This was originally a DOS OS PC when new and I Installed W7.

The problem is that it is showing 4 partition
.
1. Disk 0 Partition 1 - 125MB OEM(Reserved) 
2. Disk 0 Partition 2 - 99.7GB Primary
3. Disk 0 Partition 3 - 78.4GB System
4. Disk 0 Partition 4 - 120.8GB Primary
. 
I want to format only C Drive where Windows 7 was installed but I don't remember/can't identify which one is C.

Comment: Not necessarily if i installed Windows last time myself and chose the partition.

Comment: No its not hypothetical. I bought a DOS based pc(no OS) I partitioned and installed myself

Answer (score 0):

To identify the partitions, there's two different ways that I'd approach it.

First way, if you have another computer, I'd attach the hard drive to the other computer as a secondary. That would allow you to view the partitions to verify which drive contains windows.

Second way, download a Linux LiveCD like Ubuntu, boot off of that, and then view the partitions that way.